# Tensorflow - ValueError: Parent directory of trained_variables.ckpt doesn't exist, can't save

Tags: tensorflow

I want to save my tensorflow session `sess` but i have the following error

`ValueError: Parent directory of trained_variables.ckpt doesn't exist, can't save.`

This is my line of code :

`saver.save(sess, "trained_variables.ckpt")`

I've also tried to change the file name and put `model` instead of `trained_variables.ckpt` but i get the same problem.

Following this tutorial [A TensorFlow Tutorial: Email Classification](http://jrmeyer.github.io/tutorial/2016/02/01/TensorFlow-Tutorial.html)

Comment: I jumped into the same issue. It worked in Ubuntu but not in Windows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would guess that you're trying to save the file in a folder (directory) that doesn't exist...

Try using an absolute path for the file instead of just the bare filename.

You might want to check what your current working directory is... that could clear up things.

Does that help?

-josh

Answer (score 57):

```
saver.save(sess, "./trained_variables.ckpt")
```

Comment: This solved my problem too *but* why did this problem occur in the first place? It worked before without the `./`. Is the program shifting its location somehow?

Comment: This is simple and helpful "./" is the key for root directory where the code is running

Answer (score 10):

I've put the absoluth path of the file instead of the bare filename and it worked.
This is the final code

`saver.save(sess, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'trained_variables2.ckpt'))`

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I understand. You are trying to store the variables into the current directory, so it's weird that it's saying the parent of the current directory does not exist. Can you try this

```
v = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, 'trained_variables.ckpt')
```

This worked for me. Generally, you should always make sure that the path to where you want to store the checkpoints exist. Something like this:

```
save_path = 'checkpoints/'
model_name = 'my_model'
if not os.path.exists(save_path):
    os.makedirs(save_path)
...
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path_full = os.path.join(save_path, model_name)
with tf.Session() as sess:
   ...
   saver.save(sess, save_path_full)
```

Comment: i've put the absoluth path of the file instead of the bare filename and it worked. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did

```
 modelName = "YourModelName"
 saver.save(session, './'+modelName)
```

I believe this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

save_path should always be a path instead of a filename here. I wouldn't call it a bug, but it is better that TensorFlow could add some code to auto convert a filename "abc" to "./abc" to make it more convenient.

In [tensorflow/python/training/saver.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py):

Line:

```
save_path_parent = os.path.dirname(save_path)
```

will try to get the pathname, if you feed in only a file name without a path, *save_path_parent* will become empty and fail the later test:

```
gfile.IsDirectory(save_path_parent)
```

So you have to always provide a path + filename when using saver.save() method. Using only file name will leads to this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your current working directory:

```
import os​​
checkpoint = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chatbot_weights.ckpt')​
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux:

saver.save(sess, "trained_variables.ckpt")

For Windows:

saver.save(sess, "./trained_variables.ckpt")